# Formula that sequentially adds two cells on one WS and enters the total on another WS

Tags: excel

One spreadsheet with two worksheets (WS), on WS1, row1 create a formula that gathers the results of adding cell1+cell2 from WS2 that can be copied and pasted on WS1 down the rows that will meet this sequence, on WS1, row2 enter the results of adding cell3+cell4 from WS2. In WS1, row3 enter the results of adding cell5+cell6 from WS2 etc....

Here is an example of the two WS;

```
WS1: 
row 1   Jan   1,100.00 
row 2   Feb   1,500.00 

WS2: 
Cell 1  25-Jan  500.00 
Cell 2  10-Feb  600.00 
Cell 3  25-Feb  700.00 
Cell 4  10-Mar  800.00
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks very much Jeeped!

Answer (score 1):

Formulas don't really use *Cell 1*, *Cell 2*, etc as cell references. With *500.00* in Sheet2!C1 you can put this into any cell on Sheet1.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$1,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2,0,2,1))
```

Fill down as necessary. The [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) adjusts and shapes the range of cells being fed into the [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) although I will admit to being unclear on why Feb 10 data is being stuffed into a row labelled Jan and Mar 10 data is similarly being added to the total for Feb.